# type 1 error, type 2 error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors

alpha=p(type 1 error), beta = p(type 2 error), and total error =alphap(H0) + betap(H1) where beta is a function of alpha. One metric of the effectiveness of a hypothesis test is the integral of the intersection of the two distributions. Basically, the smaller the integral of the intersection, the better the theory, and the data are at separating the null from the alternative, so the more likely the test is to lead the tester to make a correct conclusion. In this situation any terms for this matric?

[image]

Comment: What "two distributions" are you referring to and what do you mean by their "intersection"?

Comment: @whuber in the diagram Red + Blue regions or in part. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot follow the logic that would connect this diagram to the assertions in your question, because the two distributions cannot hold at the same time, implying the areas shown have no meaning about any particular state of affairs.